# Why would Apple.com and other sites have some pages end with .html and have clean links for others. Usability advantages?

Tags: routes, usability, clean-urls

I was wondering if anyone knew the thinking behind there decision to do this:

Alot of pages on Apple.com have clean links such as:

http://www.apple.com/wifi/

however some of there pages end with .html

http://www.apple.com/airportexpress/features/airtunes.html

I find it unlikely that these pages are static html pages so....

Why would Apple (and other sites) do with, what are the usability advantages?

Comment: Implementation reasons. FWIW their default page is 'index.html'. Just because Apple does something doesn't mean it has explicit advantages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a some thought, the way I see it is the '.html' signify to the user that there is no more pages down that branch of the site. Anything that ends with '/' has a menu on it and the user can go a little deeper.

Comment: That's a reasonable enough interpretation, but do you think that Apple explicitly set up their URLs to signify this to site users? I don't.

Answer (score 1):

It means they don't understand how the web works.

Putting specific technologies into the URI is one of the most heinous crimes against the web that one could possibly commit. It means that it is pretty much guaranteed that the URI is not, in fact, a URI.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it's a hint to the end user.
Under wifi, I expect more options, contents and sub-options. It's a general starting page for wifi topic.
Under airtunes.html, I expect a list of airtunes. This is more focused.
IMHO.

Comment: At /wifi I expect information about wifi.  At /airportexpress/features/airtunes.html I expect information about airtunes features.  The html extension does not provide any semantic value.